# Using AFNetworking getting Garbage at end

Tags: ios, afnetworking, garbage

I have integrated latest framework of afnetworking but when I try to call the API using this getting **Garbage at end.** error message,  because of invalid JSON response.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution need to add below lines before doing request. Its work for me I hope this also work for you.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    post = [post stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:post parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
 }];
```